# How to get and save on txt all jenkins jobs logs

Tags: bash, jenkins, logging, groovy

I need all jenkins jobs logs(job build date, job name, tag and job builder user). How can i retrieve this information and save a txt file.

Comment: On our Jenkins installation, these files are under `jobs/<JOBNAME>/builds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this info once job completed, All you need to run a bash script in **Post-build-action**. Read each info and write to the text file in the same workspace. At the end of this, everything will print that has been write to a text file.

```
echo "Hello from jenkins Job, Testing Logs and job info"
echo "Jobe Name = ${JOB_NAME}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Jobe BUILD_TAG = ${BUILD_TAG}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Jobe BUILD_ID = ${BUILD_ID}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Jobe Started_by_user= $(cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log | grep "Started by user")" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Full Job logs= $(cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log)" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "*************************************** Job info has been write to ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt ************************"
echo "*************JOB INFO IS*********************************"
cat ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
```

[image]

You can then check the console log of your job.

[image]

**Update:**
Here is the way to make it work using the simplest pipeline example.

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {

        stage ('Hello') {
            agent any

            steps {
                echo 'Hello, '

                sh '''#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello from jenkins Job, Testing Logs and job info"
echo "Jobe Name = ${JOB_NAME}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Jobe BUILD_TAG = ${BUILD_TAG}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Jobe BUILD_ID = ${BUILD_ID}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Jobe Started_by_user= $(cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log | grep "Started by user")" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "Full Job logs= $(cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log)" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
echo "*************************************** Job info has been write to ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt ************************"
echo "*************JOB INFO IS*********************************"
cat ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-log.txt
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: We don't have post build. We have to do this as a stage in the pipeline

Comment: Oh, so the answer is based on your question and you don't mention.

Comment: btw you can run bash at any stage of your job.